# What values are evaluated to true and false without strict comparasion?

Tags: javascript, evaluate

I want to have a list of all values that will be evaluated to `true` or `false` with poor equality check like `!=`, `==` or even `if()`

I had one list that I collected throught years, but it died alog with my PC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality

"It's better to learn the coercion rules rather than try to memorize the results of god knows how many different comparisons"...

...But here's a list ;)

## ==

```
""           ==   "0"           // false
0            ==   ""            // true
0            ==   "0"           // true
false        ==   "false"       // false
false        ==   "0"           // true
false        ==   undefined     // false
false        ==   null          // false
null         ==   undefined     // true
" \t\r\n"    ==   0             // true
```

## ===

```
""           ===   "0"           // false
0            ===   ""            // false
0            ===   "0"           // false
false        ===   "false"       // false
false        ===   "0"           // false
false        ===   undefined     // false
false        ===   null          // false
null         ===   undefined     // false
" \t\r\n"    ===   0             // false
```

## Objects

```
{}                 === {};       // false
new String('foo')  === 'foo';    // false
new Number(10)     === 10;       // false

var foo = {};
foo                === foo;      // true

NaN                ==   NaN      // false
NaN                ===  NaN      // false
NaN                ==   false    // false

//NaN does not coerce using non-strict equality.
```

### Update 29/01/14:

Added `NaN` for completeness.

Comment: It's better to learn the coercion rules rather than try to memorize the results of god knows how many different comparisons

Comment: @Esailija yes, but I use the list for code-golfing to save 1 character when it is not necessary

Comment: Dude asked for a list, I gave him a list * *thumbs up* *

Comment: Yep just wanted to point out that there is no need for any lists in the first place. ;o

Comment: Just to be nice, I updated my post in your honour.

Comment: Updated the post with `NaN`. It is the only object not equal to itself and cannot be coerced to false with `==`.