# Bind an event if condition is true or else execute immediately

Tags: javascript

Is there a known pattern to replace this kind of code :

```
if(condition) {
    $(el).on("event", function() {
        doSomething();
    });
}
else {
   doSomething();
}
```

Where `doSomething` is always the same function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it up?

```
function doBindOrExecute(el, condition, func) {
  if(condition) {
      $(el).on("event", function() {
          func();
      });
  }
  else {
     func();
  }
}

doBindOrExecute(el, true, function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a short convoluted solution you can try something like this.

```
$(el).on('event', condition ? doSomething : doSomething() && false);
```

Using the [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), if `condition` is [evaluated as true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417244/818182), it will bind `'event'` to the function `doSomething`. Otherwise it will invoke `doSomething` and always use the value false so nothing is actually bound regardless of the return value from `doSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best for readability or maintenance, but you **could** do:

```
if(condition || doSomething()) {
    $(el).on("event", function() {
        doSomething();
    });
}
```

as long as `doSomething()` doesn't return a truthy value.  But wrapping it up is definitely a better way.

Comment: `|| void doSomething()` will negate any truthiness return ;)